# Any way to remove/disable feFilter from SVG background image via CSS?

Tags: css, svg

I've got an SVG file (contents below) which has an (fe)filter inside that creates an "embossed" look. I want it flat. If I remove the `filter=...` from the `<g>` tag, I get what I want.

Is there any way to do this via CSS, without having to edit the SVG file?

I can achieve this by opening the SVG directly in Chrome, and adding a rule:

```
g {filter: none !important;}
```

But where I actually need it is on a `div` which has `background-image: url(file.svg)`. I tried adding a `filter: none` on the div, as well as `div svg g` and `div g` but those have no effect.

````svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
<g filter="url(#filter0_ii_2525_53713)">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14 8C14 11.3137 11.3137 14 8.00004 14C4.6864 14 2.00012 11.3137 2.00012 8C2.00012 4.6863 4.6864 2 8.00004 2C11.3137 2 14 4.6863 14 8ZM4.45546 5.5443H10.1832C10.7709 5.5443 11.2719 6.04536 11.2657 6.63912V9.57103C11.2657 10.1586 10.7647 10.6597 10.1771 10.6597H6.02036C5.43286 10.6597 4.99986 10.1649 4.99986 9.57103V7.25144L4.25135 5.95251C4.09673 5.74226 4.22666 5.5443 4.45546 5.5443Z" fill="#1A73E8"/>
<path d="M10.1153 7.18344H6.16283C5.98954 7.18344 5.82252 7.07833 5.82252 6.91132C5.82252 6.74429 5.98968 6.63918 6.16283 6.63918H10.1153C10.2885 6.63918 10.4555 6.74429 10.4555 6.91132C10.4555 7.07833 10.2885 7.18344 10.1153 7.18344ZM10.1153 8.27214H6.16283C5.98954 8.27214 5.82252 8.16703 5.82252 8C5.82252 7.83297 5.98968 7.72786 6.16283 7.72786H10.1153C10.2885 7.72786 10.4555 7.83297 10.4555 8C10.4555 8.16703 10.2885 8.27214 10.1153 8.27214ZM9.02052 9.36696H6.15655C5.9834 9.36696 5.81639 9.26185 5.81639 9.09482C5.81639 8.9278 5.9834 8.82268 6.15655 8.82268H9.02052C9.19367 8.82268 9.36069 8.9278 9.36069 9.09482C9.36069 9.26185 9.19367 9.36696 9.02052 9.36696Z" fill="#1A73E8"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_ii_2525_53713" x="2.00012" y="1.06667" width="11.9999" height="13.8667" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="0.933333"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.466667"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.24 0"/>
<feBlend mode="overlay" in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow_2525_53713"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="-0.933333"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.466667"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.24 0"/>
<feBlend mode="multiply" in2="effect1_innerShadow_2525_53713" result="effect2_innerShadow_2525_53713"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>```
````

Comment: I would prefer that your code to be complete so that I can try a possible solution on my side before answering...

Comment: @MisterJojo - I updated with full source of SVG, thanks

Comment: You need to edit the svg if using it as a background-image

Comment: Are you having to load the image from a file or are you allowed to inline it?

Comment: @AHaworth – I have to do this on multiple SVGs that are already there and can't be modified. I need a 'general' solution to 'flatten' all the SVGs

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasnt clear in my comment. Do you have to load the SVGs from file or can you inline them? If you can't inline them I don't think you can alter them via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
g { filter: none !important; }
```

work perfectly... !:

just changed
 `width="16" height="16"`
to CSS

```
width  : 160px;
height : 160px;
```

to make the svg more visble...

```css
svg {
  width  : 160px;
  height : 160px;
  }
g {
  filter : none !important;
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_ii_2525_53713)" >
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14 8C14 11.3137 11.3137 14 8.00004 14C4.6864 14 2.00012 11.3137 2.00012 8C2.00012 4.6863 4.6864 2 8.00004 2C11.3137 2 14 4.6863 14 8ZM4.45546 5.5443H10.1832C10.7709 5.5443 11.2719 6.04536 11.2657 6.63912V9.57103C11.2657 10.1586 10.7647 10.6597 10.1771 10.6597H6.02036C5.43286 10.6597 4.99986 10.1649 4.99986 9.57103V7.25144L4.25135 5.95251C4.09673 5.74226 4.22666 5.5443 4.45546 5.5443Z" fill="#1A73E8"/>
    <path d="M10.1153 7.18344H6.16283C5.98954 7.18344 5.82252 7.07833 5.82252 6.91132C5.82252 6.74429 5.98968 6.63918 6.16283 6.63918H10.1153C10.2885 6.63918 10.4555 6.74429 10.4555 6.91132C10.4555 7.07833 10.2885 7.18344 10.1153 7.18344ZM10.1153 8.27214H6.16283C5.98954 8.27214 5.82252 8.16703 5.82252 8C5.82252 7.83297 5.98968 7.72786 6.16283 7.72786H10.1153C10.2885 7.72786 10.4555 7.83297 10.4555 8C10.4555 8.16703 10.2885 8.27214 10.1153 8.27214ZM9.02052 9.36696H6.15655C5.9834 9.36696 5.81639 9.26185 5.81639 9.09482C5.81639 8.9278 5.9834 8.82268 6.15655 8.82268H9.02052C9.19367 8.82268 9.36069 8.9278 9.36069 9.09482C9.36069 9.26185 9.19367 9.36696 9.02052 9.36696Z" fill="#1A73E8"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_ii_2525_53713" x="2.00012" y="1.06667" width="11.9999" height="13.8667" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
    <feOffset dy="0.933333"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.466667"/>
    <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.24 0"/>
    <feBlend mode="overlay" in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow_2525_53713"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
    <feOffset dy="-0.933333"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.466667"/>
    <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.24 0"/>
    <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="effect1_innerShadow_2525_53713" result="effect2_innerShadow_2525_53713"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear ... `svg` and `g` are not in the document ... they are loaded via `background-image: url(...)`. The source above is the CONTENT of the .svg ... it's not in the HTML doc.

Comment: @Dan actually, i hadn't read that in the initial post. In the case of loading in url by css, I don't think there can be a solution...Otherwise you can also put this SVG image in the background of your div with relative/absolute positioning